# Woocommerce: add text before add-to-cart only on specific single product pages

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce, message, notice

I found the following code in order to display text before the add-to-cart-button on a single product page:

```
// adds notice at single product page above add to cart

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'return_policy', 20);
function return_policy() {
if ( is_single( '11675' ) ) {
    echo '<p>My Text</p>';
    }
}
```

This works perfect!

However, I would like to show this message not only on one product page (by id), but on several product pages (by serveral ids), therefore I have to insert multiple ids. How does the above code have to changed, in order to achive this? From my barely knowledge I think that one have to insert so called arrays - but unfortunately, I do not know how to code this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use it with the help of an array then use it like this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'return_policy', 20);
function return_policy() {
   global $post;
   // create array of ids on which you want to show it
   $idsArr = [100, 105];
   if ( is_single() && in_array($post->ID, $idsArr )) {
      echo '<p>Text goes here</p>';
   }
}
```

Comment: works like a charm! would you please be so kind and provide an example of how to achieve the same result, but this time using a specific product tag instead of a product id? "

Comment: You need to use code in this way to use tag-based condition
```add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'return_policy', 20);
function return_policy() {
   global $post;
   $tagsArr = ['test1', 'test2'];
   // getting terms for current product
   $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );
   if( count($terms) > 0 ){
      foreach($terms as $term){
         $term_name = $term->name;          
         if ( is_single() && in_array(  $term_name,  $tagsArr )) {
            echo '<p>Text goes here</p>';
         }
      }
   }   
}```

Answer (score 1):

How do you will obtain the ids of those products? If there are just a few id's, you can just add them with an OR Statement.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'return_policy', 20);
function return_policy() {
if ( is_single( '85' )||is_single( '1077' )) {
    echo '<p>This will run on products 85 and 1077</p>';
    }
}
```

This is how it looks on my test site.
[image]
[image]

Comment: also works perfect, as I ad the ids manually. Is there also the possibility to have the same  result on the product page, but instead of product ids, use one or certain product tags, in order to display a specific text?